# Property with min max values

Tags: c#

I'm trying to to make a new int property called SlidingDoors. I've tried looking things up however, I can't seem find the help that I need.

EDIT: Forgot to say a min of 0 and max of 2, if it matters.

I've already got the property set up:

```
public static int SlidingDoors
{
    get
    {
        //?
    }
    set{ }
}
```

I'm still quite new to c# (and coding in general) so I might just not be looking up the right thing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you really need?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: What is the problem you have? Why can't you add the limits to your property?

Comment: What is the desired behaviour of this property if a value out of range is assigned? Should an Exception be thrown?

Comment: I'm trying to make a property with a min accepted value of 0 and a max accepted value of 2. I'm still learning now to break down my question, sorry if it doesn't clear up any confusion.

Comment: @RiderJon When people ask for clarification, it's not helpful if you simply repeat yourself, but with less detail.

Comment: Andrea, I didn't think about an exception till you mentioned it. I think all I'll need to a for the console to say "Too many doors on your car". But thank you for making me think further into my code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, you are right. I guess I don't know the right question I need to be asking. I need to see a property that will take a int for the user, then let that number be the amount of SlidingDoors on my car. The car can only have between 0 to 2 sliding doors so I just needed help writing out how to set a min and max value for a users input.

Comment: @RiderJon: You're welcome, I will leave the original version in my answer for future reference. Please do not forget to accept my answer if it meets your requirements.

Comment: What do you wan to happen if the value set for the property is outside the mentioned range?

Comment: You only needing the values 0,1,2 sounds to me that the three numbers represent three different door states. If this is is the case, you are probably better off to define an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types) and declare and use a property of your enum type instead of `int`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See edit below.

Assumed requirement: when the property is assigned a value lower than 0 or greater than 2 an ArgumentOutOfRangeExcpetion will be thrown.

Example code below:

```
    public class Example
{
    private int _propertyValue;
    public int SlidingDoors
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException((nameof(SlidingDoors)));
            }

            _propertyValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Output to console when input value out of range

```
public class Example
    {
        private int _propertyValue;
        public int SlidingDoors
        {
            get
            {
                return _propertyValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value < 0 || value > 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your message here");
                }else{

                _propertyValue = value;
    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrea, I'm sorry I still not used to how to properly ask question yet. Thank you for actually being able to understand what probably sound like toddle babel.

Comment: You're welcome and don't worry, picking up something new can be difficult and daunting. Never stop trying and it will become easier :)

Comment: This is a good approach. An alternative is to force the value to be within the required bounds, by presuming that anything greater than `2` should be `2`, and anything less than `0` should be `0`. Something like this, for example: `set { _propertyValue = Math.Min(2, Math.Max(0, value)); }`